# Is there a way to replace an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException causing value to some default value?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to replace the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds-causing value to 0.

The output that I'm hoping to get is:

```
0
10
20
30
40
0
0
0
0
0
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Please note that I do not want this for the purpose of printing (which I could do by doing a System.out.println("0") in the catch block.

```
public class test {
  int[] array;

  @Test
  public void test() {
    array = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      array[i] = i;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      try {
        System.out.println(array[i] * 10);
      }
      catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        //code to replace array[i] that caused the exception to 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No, you don't "replace" IOOBE, rather you prevent it -- never catch it, but instead write your code so that it doesn't happen

Comment: This smells of being an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it, because your current approach doesn't just look wrong, it looks dangerously wrong.

Comment: Assuming you want to solve exactly this problem what's wrong with `array[i]=0;`?

Comment: If `array[i] * 10` is an IOOBE and you catch it, then writing `array[i] = 0;` is just going to cause another IOOBE... it's the same array and the same index.

Comment: @kaya3 Good point, I'm not sure how I missed that. What exactly does the OP want to replace, then? Not `array[i]` surely since it doesn't exist to begin with. It seems they would like to extend `array` and append `0`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: There are valid scenarios where getting a default value for out of bound indices makes for much cleaner code ([convolution with extend edge handling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Edge_Handling) being a very obvious example). Python has a `list.get` method for this. It is not unreasonable to ask if Java has something similar.

Comment: @Amadan that's exactly where I need this for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions like ArrayIndexOutOfBounds generally mean there is a mistake in your code; you should treat them as cases where you need to "ask permission" first by checking the index before you access the array, rather than "seek forgiveness" by catching the exception.

Object-oriented programming is all about encapsulation of the behaviour you want. An array doesn't behave this way, so you can't use an array directly for this purpose. However, if you want something which *does* behave this way (i.e. it returns a default value when you access a non-existent index) then invent your own type of thing which does that. For example:

```java
public class DefaultArray {
    private final int defaultValue;
    private final int[] array;

    public DefaultArray(int length, int defaultValue) {
        this.array = new int[length];
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    public int get(int i) {
        // ask permission!
        if(i >= 0 && i < array.length) {
            return array[i];
        } else {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }
    public void set(int i, int value) {
        array[i] = value;
    }
    public int length() {
        return array.length;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
DefaultArray arr = new DefaultArray(5, 0);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    arr.set(i, i);
}
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr.get(i) * 10);
}
```

Output:

```
0
10
20
30
40
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed to know. It just didn't occur to me. My code looks a lot more elegant now.

Answer (score 2):

While it is certainly *cleaner* to make a custom class, if you already have an array and don't care about super-clean architecture, it is trivially easy to just make a function to do it:

```
int get(int[] array, int index, int defaultValue) {
    if (0 <= index && index < array.length) return array[index];
    else return defaultValue;
}
```